# How can I get requests to trace.axd to return 404?

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms, iis-7.5

In my production environment, I would like all requests to /trace.axd to return a HTTP 404 response. Currently, its response has a HTTP 500 status. This creates all sorts of unnecessary noise in our analytics tools. Environment is ASP.NET 4.0 web forms on IIS 7.5.

Answer (score 7):

Remove the tracing HTTP handler in the Web.config file:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- remove TraceHandler-Integrated - Remove the tracing handlers so that navigating to /trace.axd gives us a 
         404 Not Found instead of 500 Internal Server Error. -->
    <handlers>
      <remove name="TraceHandler-Integrated" />
      <remove name="TraceHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Navigating to /trace.axd now gives us a 404 Not Found instead of 500 Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 2):

First that comes to my mind is to intercept [BeginRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event in `global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    // assuming that in your production environment debugging is off
    if (!HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled && Request.RawUrl.Contains("trace.axd"))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 404;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        // or alternatively throw HttpException like this:
        // throw new HttpException(404, "");
    }
}
```